# Hadoop - Analyze log file (Java)

Tags: java, logging, hadoop

Logfile looks like this:

```
Time stamp,activity,-,User,-,id,-,data
```

--

```
2013-01-08T16:21:35.561+0100,reminder,-,User1234,-,131235467,-,-
2013-01-02T15:57:24.024+0100,order,-,User1234,-,-,-,{items:[{"prd":"131235467","count": 5, "amount": 11.6},{"prd": "13123545", "count": 1, "amount": 55.99}], oid: 5556}
2013-01-08T16:21:35.561+0100,login,-,User45687,-,143435467,-,-
2013-01-08T16:21:35.561+0100,reminder,-,User45687,-,143435467,-,-
2013-01-08T16:21:35.561+0100,order,-,User45687,-,-,-,{items:[{"prd":"1315467","count": 5, "amount": 11.6},{"prd": "133545", "count": 1, "amount": 55.99}], oid: 5556}
...
...
```

**Edit**

Concrete example from this log:

`User1234` has got a `reminder` - this `reminder` has `id`=`131235467`, after this he made an `order` with following `data` : `{items:[{"prd":"131235467","count": 5, "amount": 11.6},{"prd": "13123545", "count": 1, "amount": 55.99}], oid: 5556}`
In this case `id` and `prd` of `data` are the same, so i want sum up `count`*`amount` -> in this case 5*11.6 = 58 and output it like

```
User 1234    Prdsum: 58
```

`User45687` made also an `order` but he didn't received a `reminder` so **no** sum up of his `data`

Output:

```
User45687    Prdsum: 0
```

Final Output of this log:

```
User 1234    Prdsum: 58    
User45687    Prdsum: 0
```

My Question is: How can i compare(?) this values -> `id` and `prd` in `data`?
The key is the user. Would a custom Writable be useful -> value= (id, data). I need some ideas.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend getting the raw output sum as you are doing as the result of the first pass of one Hadoop job, so at the end of the Hadoop job, you have a result like this:

```
User1234     Prdsum: 58    
User45687    Prdsum: 0
```

and then have a second Hadoop job (or standalone job) that compares the various values and produces another report.

Do you need "state" as part of the first Hadoop job? If so, then you will need to keep a HashMap or HashTable in your mapper or reducer that stores the values of all the keys (users in this case) to compare - but that is not a good setup, IMHO. You are better off just doing an aggregate in one Hadoop job, and doing the comparison in another.

Comment: User1234 had an order with 2 prd, so when i would sum up the output it would have a) {"prd":"131235467","count": 5, "amount": 11.6} --> 5*11,6 = 58 and b) {"prd": "13123545", "count": 1, "amount": 55.99} --> 1*55,99 = 55,99. But i'm only interessted in a) since prd of a == id of reminder. When i take the raw output sum in the first job. How can i distinguish in the 2nd job which sum is the one i'm looking for (reminder.id == data.prd)? Or do i understand your answer wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve is by using a composite key.
Mapper output Key is combination of userid, event id (reminder -> 0, order -> 1). Partition data using userid and you need to write your own comparator.
here is the gist.

**Mapper**

```
for every event check the event type 
    if event type is "reminder"
        emit : <User1234,0> <reminder id>
    if event type is "order"
        split if you have multiple orders
        for every order
            emit : <User1234,1> <prd, count* amount, other interested blah>
```

Partition using userid so all entries with same user is will go to same reducer.

**Reducer**

At reducer all entries will be grouped by userid and sorted event id (i.e first you will get all reminders for a given userid and followed by orders).

```
If `eventid` is 0
    add reminders id to a set (`reminderSet`).

If `eventid` is is 1 &&  prd is in `remindersSet` 
   emit : `<userid>  <prdsum>`
else 
   emit : `<userid>  <0>`
```

More details on Composite key can be found in 'Hadoop definitive guide' or [here](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/secondary-sorting-aka-sorting-values-in-hadoops-mapreduce-programming-paradigm/)